# Supertab: autocomplete after a specific word followed by a space

Tags: vim, jedi-vim, supertab

By default, supertab is inserting a regular tab when the previous character is a space.

I would like to keep this behaviour but with the following exception: if the previous character is a space but the preceding word is `import`, autocomplete.

For instance (`|` denotes the cursor position)

- `from numpy import |<tab>` should display completions,
- `for |<tab>` should insert a tab.

I'm aware of `g:SuperTabNoCompleteAfter` but I'm not sure how to obtain the desired result.

Comment: I wanted to use “g:SuperTabNoCompleteAfter” but I didn’t know which argument to use. So not much.

Answer (score 2):

supertab has the ability to consider the preceding text to choose a completion type. You need to teach the plugin about the `import` context, and configure it to use a custom completion, e.g. user completion (`<C-x><C-u>`). Then implement the corresponding completion (or find another plugin that already does this), and you should be good.

#### References

- [context completion](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab/blob/40fe711e088e2ab346738233dd5adbb1be355172/doc/supertab.txt#L78-L85) at `:help supertab-defaultcompletion`
- [completion contexts](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab/blob/40fe711e088e2ab346738233dd5adbb1be355172/doc/supertab.txt#L125) at `:help supertab-completioncontexts`
- Writing a custom completion at `:help complete-functions`.